# How to detect sse availability in CMake

Tags: build, cross-platform, cmake, sse

In a CMakeLists.txt file, is there a way to detect the highest level of SSE available, and save it to CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS? In other words, I'd like to be able to write something like:

```
FindSSE()  # defines SSE_FLAGS
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${SSE_FLAGS})
```

For example, if the platform supports up to SSE level 3, then FindSSE() would set SSE_FLAGS to -msse3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be overkill, but the [OptimizeForArchitecture.cmake](https://github.com/VcDevel/Vc/blob/master/cmake/OptimizeForArchitecture.cmake) from vc on gitorious will provide a list of optimizations based on the architecture.

You could either use that script directly or trim it down to the code you need.

A *better* solution would be to make a small cmake test script that uses SSE instructions and check if each variant compiles/runs.

EDIT: More specifically, there's also [FindSSE.cmake](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hideo55/CMake-FindSSE/master/FindSSE.cmake) in various places, although it still uses the somewhat clunky method of parsing `/proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: The above suggestion only works for Linux.  There is a giant "TODO" on it for Windows.

Comment: FWIW, the updated links are [OptimizeForArchitecture.cmake](https://github.com/VcDevel/Vc/blob/master/cmake/OptimizeForArchitecture.cmake) and [FindSSE.cmake](https://github.com/VcDevel/Vc/blob/master/cmake/FindSSE.cmake).

Comment: Both `.cmake` links are broken now.